# Eclipse is not resolving eventhandler with autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, events, javafx, autocomplete

i am new to java and javafx. I have the following code and everything is working fine when i run the program. The code compiles successfully:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox root = new HBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            
            Button b1 = new Button("Click me");
            
            b1.setText("Click this button");
            
            b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    b1.setText("Button clicked");
                }
            });
            
            root.getChildren().add(b1);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is the following.
When i am writing the part...

```
b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
```

... eclipse not autocompletes the rest, what it should do:

```
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    b1.setText("Button clicked");
                }
            });
```

Additionally when i write "new EventHandler" eclipse shows the message "The type eventhandler can not be instantiated".

Can please anyone help me why this message comes up and what is to do that eclipse is autocompleting the EventHandler? Maybe the message prevents eclipse from autocompleting?

I have searched for hours but i can not find the solution for my problem :(. Would be great if someone could help me!

Many thanks for your help!

Content of module-info.java:

```
module MyJavaFXApp {

requires java.desktop;
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.base;

opens application to javafx.controls, javafx.base, javafx.graphics;
}
```

Comment: Please show in which way you have included the `EventHandler` interface to the project's _Java Build Path_ so it can be resolved. Tell also which Java version do you use in your project and also add the content of the `module-info.java` file to your question, if it exists.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for your answer. Java Runtime 11 (jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot) and JavaFX18.0.2 are added to buildpath. Both as "Modulepath".

Comment: @howlger content of module-info added for you to question

Comment: hmm ... what I see: typing _button.setOn_ , then choose from auto complete popup _button.setOnAction(null)_, replace the null by typing _new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()_ - until here the error is _cannot instantiate_ - then type the curly bracket and press enter (alternatively type both curly brackets): the error changes to _must implement methods_ , then ctrl-1 offer to implement it for me. Is that what you are also seeing? It's what I would expect ..

Comment: Thanks for the information. This sounds like a bug of an older version of Eclipse. Are you sure your Eclipse is up to date? What shows _Help > About Eclipse IDE_?

Comment: @howlger thanks for response. it shows the following: Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for your help! yes you are right! thats the same like i see... i tried what you sayed step by step ... then the auto implementation works for me too ! i thought that eclipse will do autocomplete when typing "new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()" after pressing enter.  howlger said it sounds like a bug. kleopatra you showed a way. the question is, is it a bug or is it a feature :D?

Comment: If there would no code completion proposals for `new EventH`, it would be a bug. In your case you should better use code completion already at `b1.setOnAction(` and choose the first proposal _(ActionEvent event) -> : void - EventHandler_ to get a lambda expression for better readability: `b1.setOnAction​(event -> b1.setText("Button clicked"));`.